# How to make query in Ruby on Rails where if any param from form are empty the query doesn't check this param?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have estate form with fields:

1. estate_type - house, flat
2. surface_min
3. surface_max
4. price_min
5. price_max

Fields in Estates database:

1. estate_type

   2. surface
   3. price

And I want to make a query to find for example:
Find flat where surface> 40 AND surface<100 AND the price_min>200000 but price_max is not important for me in this query. So the params[:price_max] is empty.
But in next query someone maybye wants to find by surface and price.
So, I don't now how make query where some params from form sometimes are empty and sometimes not.

Comment: If you could post the `params` there is probably better implementations for this such as if these are stored in say `params[:search]` then something as simple as `search_params = params[:search].reject {|_,v|  v.empty? }` would probably work will for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually do it like this:

```
@estates = Estate.all # or another default scope
@estates = @estates.where(surface_min: params[:surface_min]) if params[:surface_min]
@estates = @estates.where(surface_max: params[:surface_max]) if params[:surface_max]
...
```

A bit more effort is needed if you need range queries and not straight equality checks. But it seems that the problematic part for you was how to do the optional filtering. This answer addresses just that.

Comment: no need for `.all`, it would fire an unnecessary query

Comment: @skam: no, it wouldn't.

Comment: I add ".present?" to your "if":
@estates=@estates.where('surface> ?', params[:surface_from]) if params[:surface_from].present?
    @estates=@estates.where('surface< ?', params[:surface_to]) if params[:surface_to].present?
And now I have correct query:
SELECT "estates".* FROM "estates" INNER JOIN "developers" ON "developers"."id" = "estates"."developer_id" WHERE (estate_type ='flat') AND (developers.company='Budimex') AND (surface< '100')

Comment: Thanx for help :)

Comment: Regarding @skams comment this is rails version specific. I believe prior to rails 4. `ActiveRecord::Base#all` fired immediately and returned an `Array` as of rails 4 it is essentially the same as the now removed `Model.scoped` which returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` scope. So basically unless you are still running rails 3 (which you shouldn't be) you are correct